# Remove btn class from f.button in bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I am building a signin form in rails and using bootstrap for styling.

I am using the following as a submit button

```
= f.button :submit, "Sign In", class: 'btn-custom success'
```

The only problem is when it comes out in html, it includes bootstraps "btn" class, how can I remove this?

Comment: You can use `button_tag`.  Here is the doc: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-button_tag

Comment: Thankyou, if you put your comment as an answer ill select it as the answer!

Comment: glad to be of help.  Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are not using rails default form helper as rails default does not add extra classes i.e. `btn` in your case.  There are several ways you can add a submit button without extra attributes or "attribute values"(in your case):

**Html button:**

```
<button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn-custom success">Sign In</button>
```

**HTML input:**

```
<input type="submit" value="Sign In" class="btn-cusom success" />
```

**Rails `button_tag`**

```
= button_tag 'Sign In', type: :submit, class: 'btn-custom success'
```

Please refer to http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-button_tag for documentation of `button_tag` helper specifically and the page for other options.

**Rails `submit_tag`**

```
= submit_tag 'Sign In', class: 'btn-custom success'
```

Please refer to http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-submit_tag for documentation of `submit_tag`.  The only point to note in this case is that the `submit_tag` helper adds a `name` attribute with value `commit` by default.

But since your question is related to `button`, you could either use the "HTML button" or "Rails button_tag" options.